# useState for mouse down event not working with Canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, html5-canvas

I am making a drawing app with React and Canvas. However, if I set the `isMouseDown` variable as `useState` instead of `useRef`, the canvas is not drawing and I cannot seem to find why. Here is the component:

```js
function App() {
  const [isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown] = useState(false);
  const isMouseDownRef = useRef(false);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const ctx = useRef(null);

  function triggerMouseDown() {
    setIsMouseDown(true);
    //isMouseDownRef.current = true;
  }

  function triggerMouseUp() {
    setIsMouseDown(false);
    //isMouseDownRef.current = false;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(canvasRef.current) {
      ctx.current = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
      canvasRef.current.width = 720;
      canvasRef.current.height = 480;
      canvasRef.current.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        draw(
          e.clientX - canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().left, 
          e.clientY - canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top
        )
      })

      canvasRef.current.addEventListener("mousedown", triggerMouseDown)

      window.addEventListener("mouseup", triggerMouseUp)
    }

    return () => {
      canvasRef.current.removeEventListener("mousedown", triggerMouseDown);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", triggerMouseUp)
    }
  }, [])

  function draw(x, y) {
    if(isMouseDown) {
      ctx.current.beginPath();
      ctx.current.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.current.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.current.stroke();
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <canvas id="canvas1" ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(isMouseDown)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know it's not supposed to be a `useState`, beacause it would rerender too much, but I am interested in why it's not working with `useState` in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes inside your code:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [mouseData, setMouseData] = React.useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);
  const ctx = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(canvasRef.current) {
      ctx.current = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
      canvasRef.current.width = 720;
      canvasRef.current.height = 480;
    }

  }, [canvasRef])

  function Draw(e) {      
      ctx.current.beginPath();
      ctx.current.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.current.arc(mouseData.x, mouseData.y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.current.stroke();
  }
  const SetPos = (e) => {
    setMouseData({
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
    });
};


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <canvas id="canvas1" ref={canvasRef}
      onMouseEnter={(e) => SetPos(e)}
      onMouseMove={(e) => SetPos(e)}
      onMouseDown={(e) => SetPos(e)}
      onMouseMove={(e) => Draw(e)}
      ></canvas>
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(mouseData)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me find why it was not working with useState.

Answer (score 0):

Y_T has the right idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74575138/6243352). There's no need for `useEffect`, but if you *do* use one, it should use `isMouseDown` in the capture group so that it triggers adding/removing the move listener at the appropriate time. `clearRect` is optional. Something like (click and drag to draw):

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (!mouseDown) {
    return;
  }

  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const onMouseMove = e => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
  };
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

  return () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  };
}, [mouseDown]);
```

But since React gives `onMouseMove`, we can just use that instead of managing it ourselves:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = React.useState(false);
  const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleMouseMove = e => {
    if (!mouseDown) {
      return;
    }

    const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left;
    const offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // optional
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(offsetX, offsetY, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  return (
    <canvas
      onMouseDown={() => setMouseDown(true)}
      onMouseUp={() => setMouseDown(false)}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      ref={canvasRef}
      width="720"
      height="480"
    ></canvas>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think using inline events was so useful.